# cocotb: access arrays of instances signals

Tags: verification, cocotb

I have modules that initialized like that

RTL

```
slave slaves[1:0] (some inputs / outputs)
```

I need to access some internal data from slaves instances which have the following hdl hierarchy

> top.slaves[0].internal_data
> top.slaves[1].internal_data

when I tried the following code in cocotb

```
signal_0 = self.dut.slaves[0].internal_data.value
signal_1 = self.dut.slaves[1].internal_data.value
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: dut contains no object named slaves
```

The output of print(dir(self.dut)) are:

> [...,'**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', ... , 'clock',..., 'salves[0]', 'slaves[1]',....]

clearly it can't see the [0] or [1] as part of the instance name. How can I access signals like these ?

Comment: Have you try to print dut object elements with python dir() ? `print(dir(self.dut))`

Comment: I tried it. I can see 'slaves[0]' and 'slaves[1]' in the output but when I try print(dir(self.dut.slaves[1])) I got error say "dut contains no object named slaves"

Comment: If you try just `print(dir(self.dut.slaves))` without `[]` ?

Comment: get the same error: dut contains no object named slaves

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `print(dir(self.dut))` ?

Comment: Does it work with `self.dut._id("slaves[0]", extended=False).value`?

Comment: Yes that works fine thank you very much. Please, add it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work with self.dut._id("slaves[0]", extended=False).value?

Answer (score 0):

If using GHDL:

1. Make sure you are running an up-to-date version and NOT 0.38
2. Accessing constant arrays through VPI is not supported as of Jan 6, 2023. Check this [issue](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues/2300).

P.S: to add my grain of salt to the original post, it seems that there was a typo (salves instead of slaves).